# C# Connect to Wifi Network with Managed Wifi API

Tags: c#, networking, wifi

i was wondering if it is possible to connect to a wifi network with the Managed Wifi API?

Answer (score 11):

Basically, yes.

Maybe you should spend a few minutes searching. From [Managed Wifi API codeplex page:](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/)

> The library uses the Native Wifi API, ...

So going to Native Wifi API: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa816369(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Connect to or disconnect from a wireless network. See WlanConnect and WlanDisconnect.

And furthermore, in the source code of Managed Wifi API [WlanApi.cs](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#WlanApi.cs):

```
/// <summary>
/// Requests a connection (association) to the specified wireless network.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// The method returns immediately. Progress is reported through the <see cref="WlanNotification"/> event.
/// </remarks>
public void Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode connectionMode, Wlan.Dot11BssType bssType, string profile)
{
    Wlan.WlanConnectionParameters connectionParams = new Wlan.WlanConnectionParameters();
    connectionParams.wlanConnectionMode = connectionMode;
    connectionParams.profile = profile;
    connectionParams.dot11BssType = bssType;
    connectionParams.flags = 0;
    Connect(connectionParams);
}
```

And the unique sample of the website is doing it! [Sample](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/41381#WifiExample/WifiExample.cs)

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
    foreach ( WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces )
    {
        // Lists all networks with WEP security
        Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList( 0 );
        foreach ( Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks )
        {
            if ( network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm == Wlan.Dot11CipherAlgorithm.WEP )
            {
                Console.WriteLine( "Found WEP network with SSID {0}.", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid));
            }
        }

        // Retrieves XML configurations of existing profiles.
        // This can assist you in constructing your own XML configuration
        // (that is, it will give you an example to follow).
        foreach ( Wlan.WlanProfileInfo profileInfo in wlanIface.GetProfiles() )
        {
            string name = profileInfo.profileName; // this is typically the network's SSID
            string xml = wlanIface.GetProfileXml( profileInfo.profileName );
        }

        // Connects to a known network with WEP security
        string profileName = "Cheesecake"; // this is also the SSID
        string mac = "52544131303235572D454137443638";
        string key = "hello";
        string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><hex>{1}</hex><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>WEP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>networkKey</keyType><protected>false</protected><keyMaterial>{2}</keyMaterial></sharedKey><keyIndex>0</keyIndex></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", profileName, mac, key);
        wlanIface.SetProfile( Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true );
        wlanIface.Connect( Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName );
    }
}
```

Have a good day!

Comment: Is it possible do specify which Network interface I can use to connect, given the fact my machinne has multiple wifi keyboards?

Answer (score 5):

There are APIs in Windows 10 that can do this.

See [WiFiAdapter class on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.wifi.wifiadapter?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and some [sample code for UWP on GitHub](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/WiFiConnector/CS)

The nice thing I see over the managed API is you don't have to deal with creating an XML profile to connect to a new network. You can actually connect to a network with just a password.

Comment: Thanks for the link of iot samples.