# Connecting to wifi in c# using ManagedWifi

Tags: c#, wifi

i am trying to connect to wifi networks from my code. i found that Managedwifi is a good way. and i use it to scan the wifi networks and it is good. but the thing is that i can't connect to a network and i can't find a sample code on the internet. i have googled it but no result!
please help me to connect to a network!
this is the tryed code!

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
        {
            // Lists all available networks
            Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
            foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found network with SSID {0} || Secured : {1}.", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid),network.securityEnabled);
            }
            //wlanIface.DeleteProfile("Xperia Arc");
            //string profileName = GetStringForSSID(networks[0].dot11Ssid); // this is also the SSID
            string profileName = "Xperia Arc";
            string mac = "52544131303235572D454137443638";
            string key = "9090090900";
            string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><hex>{1}</hex><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>WEP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>networkKey</keyType><protected>false</protected><keyMaterial>{2}</keyMaterial></sharedKey><keyIndex>0</keyIndex></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", profileName, mac, key);
            try
            {
                wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
                wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error Occured!");
                //throw;
            }
            while (wlanIface.InterfaceState.ToString()=="Associating")
            {
                ;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(wlanIface.InterfaceState.ToString() + wlanIface.);
            //Console.WriteLine(wlanIface.CurrentConnection.profileName +" "+ wlanIface.InterfaceState.ToString());
        }

    }

    static string GetStringForSSID(Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);
    }
```

Comment: and can any one tell me what is mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Connect to Wifi Network with Managed Wifi API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808620/c-sharp-connect-to-wifi-network-with-managed-wifi-api)

Answer (score 3):

For general usage of [ManagedWifi](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) see: [C# Connect to Wifi Network with Managed Wifi API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808620/c-sharp-connect-to-wifi-network-with-managed-wifi-api)

Your question regarding the "mac" in the profile xml: Its the ssid as hex representation.

Your code has multiple problems:

- Don't run over all interfaces and connect to the same wifi network, just use the first available interface
- Your while loop waiting for the interface state "Association" wouldn't work, as usually the interface will still be in the "Disconnected" state. So better just wait until "Connected" or timeout.

So your code should look like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface = client.Interfaces.FirstOrDefault();

        if(wlanIface == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Wifi Interface available!");
            throw new Exception("No Wifi Interface available!");
        }

        // Lists all available networks
        Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
        foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Found network with SSID {0} || Secured : {1}.", GetStringForSSID(network.dot11Ssid),network.securityEnabled);
        }

        string profileName = "Xperia Arc";
        string ssid = profileName;
        byte[] ssidBytes = Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(ssid);
        string ssidHex = BitConverter.ToString(ssidBytes);
        ssidHex = ssidHex.Replace("-", "");
        string key = "9090090900";

        string profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><hex>{1}</hex><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>open</authentication><encryption>WEP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>networkKey</keyType><protected>false</protected><keyMaterial>{2}</keyMaterial></sharedKey><keyIndex>0</keyIndex></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", ssid, ssidHex, key);

        try
        {
            wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);
            wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error Occured!");
            //throw;
        }

        int timeout = 3000;
        while ((wlanIface.InterfaceState.ToString()<>"Connected") && (timeout >= 0))
        {
               System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
               timeout -= 500;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(wlanIface.InterfaceState.ToString() + wlanIface);
        //Console.WriteLine(wlanIface.CurrentConnection.profileName +" "+ wlanIface.InterfaceState.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: this causes error when wifi device is more than one. could I ask about solution?

Comment: Please open a new question with detailed error description and your code...

Comment: wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, ssid, WlanConnectionFlags.AdhocJoinOnly);