# How to block all web requests on Windows 10, unless my custom whitelist approves it?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I'd like to write a very simple web traffic blocker for my kids using C#. I'm an experienced C# developer. I'd like the following basic features:

- The whitelist is linked to a specific Windows 10 user account (the program would know who is logged in)
- All websites blocked unless specifically whitelisted
- This little piece of software cannot be shutdown or uninstalled except by the admin
- When a blocked site is attempted to be accessed, a pop-up would come up from my program that allows the user to request access.
- This program needs to be lower-level than any browser, so it blocks traffic in all browsers, and even programs that embed browser controls or browser-like capabilities. I'm guessing the OS is aware when web requests are initiated and which sites are being requested, so I need to know how to tap into that OS-level event.

I've never done any programming that blocks web traffic so I'm looking for a source code example of doing this. Also how can I prevent the software from being stopped or removed, unless a password is supplied?

I'm asking for advice and to be pointed in the right direction. Minimal code samples or links that demonstrate how to accomplish my requirements would be very helpful.

Note: I have searched and can't find anything that quite works the way I want, so I'd like to build my own.

Comment: To do this reliably you need to write some sort of **DLL injectio*n to jump into the address space of running applications and proxy all calls to sockets to manipulate them as desired (Ideally at kernel mode, where you can also listen for create process and it couldn't be uninstalled). You could use *SetWindowHookEx* in user mode, but wont be 100% bullet proof,  there are libraries that do this hard-work and all you will have to do is write the proxy code, also it cant do it in C#. Id suggest taking a look at the [Madshi Madhook library](http://www.madshi.net/madCodeHookDescription.htm)

Comment: It would make more sense to just do this from your router, or get some off-the-shelf firewall software or solution

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel. Most routers allow you turn on a whitelist system. If you don’t want to be hindered with it, get another router which your child’s computer connects to. Now you might say "But windows doesn’t let you control which WiFi networks for individual users", this is where you can write some C#. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808620/c-sharp-connect-to-wifi-network-with-managed-wifi-api

Comment: I'd suggest having a look at https://www.koalasafe.com for a router based solution. Or use https://au.pcmag.com/software/54889/gallery/microsoft-family-safety-for-windows-10 if you are willing to force them to use Edge as the web browser.

Comment: Anyway truthfully as interesting as this question is, its too broad