# How can I connect to a Wifi network in C#

Tags: c#, network-programming, wifi

I'm trying to connect to a wifi network in C#, but unfortunatly I didn't find anything...
I have the Name of the Wifi network and the password, and want to write it in the promt. Then the code tries to connect and answers with connect successful or no password wrong or something like that.

Comment: You need to improve your search ability, e.g. [`[c#] connect wifi answers:1`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+connect+wifi+answers%3A1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Connect to Wifi Network with Managed Wifi API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25808620/c-sharp-connect-to-wifi-network-with-managed-wifi-api)

Comment: You just need to use a HTTP library.  Most servers are using HTTPS and authentication using OAUTH2.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/ and